# SFINAE method existence check - with/out a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae

The following code seems to be a decent SFINAE way to check for the existence of a method with no parameters:

```
template<typename T> struct has_size_method {
private:
    typedef std::true_type yes;
    typedef std::false_type no;
    template<typename U> static auto test(int) 
        -> decltype(std::declval<U>().size() == 1, yes());
    template<typename> static no test(...);
public:
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<decltype(test<T>(0)),yes>::value;
};
```

(lifted from [here](https://dev.krzaq.cc/post/checking-whether-a-class-has-a-member-function-with-a-given-signature/)). How do I adapt that for taking a parameter? The following

```
template<typename T, typename Key> struct has_find_method {
private:
    typedef std::true_type yes;
    typedef std::false_type no;
    template<typename U> static auto test(int)
        -> decltype(std::declval<U>().find(std::declval<const Key&>()) == 1, yes());
    template<typename> static no test(...);
public:
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<decltype(test<T>(0)),yes>::value;
};
```

[doesn't work, although it does compile](https://godbolt.org/z/caGY7K) (GodBolt). What am I doing wrong?

Note: While this question stands on its own merit (I believe), it's also an X-Y question. I need a C++11-compatible find function which also works for maps (but without using Boost or something heavy like that.)

Comment: There's a much shorter (and more readable, IMO) way to write this kind of checks: `template <typename T, typename = void> struct foo : std::false_type{}; template <typename T> struct foo<T, CONDITION_HERE> : std::true_type {};`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: And what's the condition for the existence of the method, then?

Comment: `decltype(void(std::declval<U>().size() == 1))`, for example. You can have several comma-separated `void(...)` checks inside of `decltype(...)`. If you also need a boolean condition, you can wrap the `decltype` in `std::enable_if_t`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I'll try that too.

Answer (score 5):

`std::unordered_map::find()` returns an iterator and you compare its return value against 1. Remove that `== 1` part and see what happens then.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter, simpler, enable-if-like solution due to @HolyBlackCat :

```
template <typename T, typename Key, typename = void>
struct has_find_method : std::false_type{};

template <typename T, typename Key>
struct has_find_method<
    T, Key, decltype( void(std::declval<T>().find(std::declval<const Key&>())) )
> : std::true_type {};
```